# How to interpolate a list into an f-string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.6, f-string

Say I have a function

```
def foo(): return [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to interpolate the result of the function into a string to get `"001 002 003"`. I've tried this:

```
f"{*foo():03d 03d 03d}"
```

But it produced `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`. Can I do this using an f-string?

Comment: `f"{' '.join(map('{:03d}'.format, foo()))}"`?

Comment: The suggestion works, but the f-string is redundant and the syntax verbose. One can just use the similar answer by @ev-kounis, without f-string. It seems f-strings do not improve the printing of lists.

Answer (score 7):

is this what you are looking for?

```
str_repr = ' '.join(map('{:03d}'.format, foo()))
print(str_repr)  # prints: 001 002 003
```

maybe the best thing about this solution is that it works with any list length and with minimal tweaking you can change the output format too.

Comment: This works, but it does **not** make use of f-strings as requested. It may indeed be the best available Python solution, but it is verbose. I wish something like this `f"{foo():03d}"` would thread over the list.

Answer (score 6):

Starred expressions are only allowed in few specific contexts, such as function calls, list/tuple/set literals, etc. An f-string placeholder is not one of them, apparently. You could format each element individually and join the strings, e.g.:

```
lst = foo()
s = ' '.join(f'{x:03d}' for x in lst)  # '001 002 003'
```

Generally, to format multiple values you have to use a separate placeholder for each value.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` operator (similar rules exist for `**`) can only be used inside:

- a function call: `foo(*bar)`
- a list, tuple, or set literal: `['foo', *bar]`
- an assignment: `foo, *bar = range(10)`

It is not an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) and can therefore not be used inside the braces of f-strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the zfill method instead:

```
s_repr=" ".join([str(x).zfill(3) for x in foo()]) #not very PEP8 =S
```

Answer (score 0):

For lists, f-strings do not seem to add much to what was already possible without them. An alternative, slightly simpler, solution **without** f-strings and without `.join`, which works for any list length, is the following

```
a = foo()
str_repr = ("{:03d} "*len(a)).format(*a)
print(str_repr)  # prints: 001 002 003
```